# C# Windows Forms Programming user control which consists of three images

Tags: c#, winforms

I  try to create a user control (button). The button background consists of three images. The left border of the button, the right border and middle part that stretched depending on the text. How can I realized this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have to derive from Button (or Control, depends how deep you want to go) and override OnPaint. You will have to handle all states (normal, pushed) and be responsible for refreshing them. Like here for example:

http://christian-helle.blogspot.com/2007/09/buttonex-owner-drawn-button-control.html

Comment: I don't understand how cal I draw background with 3 different pictures like picture 1 "[", picture 2  "|"  picture 3 "]" In the end i want to saw something like this [||||||||]

Comment: in the OnPaint method you just compose / draw the image from those 3 images you want. Take a look at System.Drawing.Graphics namespace